# Converting an XML file into an object

Tags: javascript, xml, intel

I'm trying to use the Planetside 2 database to create a simple application for educational purposes. However, I'm stuck. I need to convert an XML file to a Javascript object so i can use the data easily and display it on my app. Problem is, the file is a link, i suppose. I tried it just like you would with a file located on the same server/PC however that doesnt work.

This is the link:
http://census.daybreakgames.com/xml/get/ps2:v2/character/?name.first_lower=litebrite

My question is, How do i convert/turn this onto an object usable in Javascript? (I have absolute no experience in javascript, hence the reason i'm not using the JSON verion of the file)

Thanks

Comment: I you have 0 javascript experience, why are you doing this at all? You might consider picking up a tutorial or two first. If you had just a tiny bit experience, JSON would still be a million times easier than xml. In both cases you use javascript, but with JSON you _start_ with a javascript object, and don't convert to it first.

Comment: That website doesn't allow cross-origin requests. You want be able to get this info clientside, you'll need to use some server-side technology.